Modify custom-columns output in kubectl commands
I'm trying to customize the output of the command kubectl get hpa with the -o flag. If I run
kubectl get hpa -o=custom-columns='MEMORY:.status.currentMetrics[1].resource.current.averageValue'

I get
MEMORY
22466478

which is the current memory utilization in bytes and not very human readable. I'd like to convert it to megabytes within the command output, so that I get something like
MEMORY
22.47MB

Is it possible to do this within the kubectl command (i.e. without some kind of wrapper)?
(note: there will be more columns than this in the final output. I've presented a minimal version for simplicity's sake)

MegaByte means 2^20 bytes, 2^20which gives 1048576. It seems you converted the memory value (22466478) into mega byte by using memory value%1000000(22466478%1000000) but you are supposed to use memory value%1048576(22466478%1048576) to get the exact memory value in Mega Bytes.
Kubectl does not directly support arithmetic operations in the command line. So you can try using ‘jq’ command like below :

kubectl get hpa-o json | jq -r ‘.items[] | [.metadata.name, (.status.currentMetrics[] | select(.resource.name==”memory”).resource.current.averageValue' | tonumber / (1024*1024) | tostring + “MB”)] | @tsv

kubectl get hpa-o json it fetches the Horizontal Pod Autoscaling(HPA) resource in JSON format.
Jq processes the JSON output. @tsv for tab-separated values for better visibility. It is in a decimal place. And if you are working with linux, by using numfmt (which converts numbers from/to human-readable format ) also we can get.

kubectl get hpa-o custom-colunms=”MEMORY:status.currentMetrics1.resource.current.averageValue” -- no-headers | numfmt --to=iec

and refer to the Ostechnix article written by SK on The Numfmt Command tutorial for more details. It is in the format of human readable form with IEC standard.
Another way is using the ‘awk’ command for getting the decimal value like below :

kubectl get hpa-o custom-colunms=”MEMORY:status.currentMetrics1.resource.current.averageValue” -- no-headers | awk ‘{printf “%.2f MB\n”, $1 / (1024*1024)}’

This converts memory usage byte to megabyte with decimal value.

Refer to this similar  StackExchange Unix & Linux link for more information.

A good answer. Also, a principle of UNIX is for tools to do one thing well. kubectl interacts with the Kubernetes API server, jq and awk are good tools for formatting output.
